# How do I set file type icons on macOS for my app?

Tags: macos, file, file-type

On Windows, I can do this by adding entries to the registry. As far as I know, macOS has no such thing so how do apps set the corresponding file type icons for their format?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, click on the project (the very upper-left-most item in the Project navigator), and then select your application's target in the content pane. In the "Info" tab, you will see "Document Types". This is where you can define the document types your app supports, as well as the icons that are associated with them. If this is set up correctly in your app, the OS will automatically handle setting the icons for files that your app supports.

Comment: to add to that, the systems learn about your app either when it is launched or moved into /Applications or your ~/Applications dir...

Comment: I don't think you even have to launch it; just viewing it in the Finder should be enough for the OS to pick up on it.